# How to add multiple stop points for routing using ArcGIS in Android

Tags: arcgis-10.2, java, routing, android, maps

I have a project where in I have a source and a destination, but in between there can be any number of stop points. I need to display a route from source to destination covering all the stop points.

I started finding route between two points and is working fine. But the moment I add a extra point in between it gives a error saying

> Location "Location 3" in "Stops" is unlocated. Location "Location 2" in "Stops" is on a soft-restricted network element. Cannot preserve last location "Location 3" in "Stops" because it is invalid. "Stops" does not contain valid input for any route.

I tried googling for this error but couldn't find any results.

I thought location 3 is not a valid location but when I try to find a route between source and location 3 it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below I have attached function which gives route result.

```
private void QueryDirections(final ArrayList<Point> stopPoints) {

dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RoutingSample.this, "Routing Sample",
        "Calculating route...", true);
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Start building up routing parameters
            NAFeaturesAsFeature stops = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
            ArrayList<StopGraphic> stopGraphics = new ArrayList<StopGraphic>();
            for(Point pt : stopPoints){
                stopGraphics.add(new StopGraphic(pt));
            }
            Graphic[] stopGraphicsPrim = new Graphic[stopGraphics.size()];
            stopGraphicsPrim = stopGraphics.toArray(stopGraphicsPrim);
            stops.setSpatialReference(wm);
            stops.setFeatures(stopGraphicsPrim);
            stops.setCompressedRequest(true);
            RouteParameters rp = mRouteTask
                    .retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
            rp.setStops(stops);
            rp.setReturnDirections(true);
            rp.setFindBestSequence(true);
            rp.setPreserveFirstStop(true);
            rp.setOutSpatialReference(wm);

            // I get error here. When routeTast.solve is called. Please help

            mResults = mRouteTask.solve(rp);
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mException = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"directions cannot be found ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
// Start the operation
t.start();
```

}

I was referring to a similar post [Finding shortest route between multiple stops using ArcGIS for Android?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141556) but I wasn't able to get any solution from this.